# Threaded Server with QtConcurrent::run

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt4

I'm trying to develop a threaded server that contains a run method which is to run in another thread with QtConcurrent::run.

### My first question is:

Am I right, when I don't create a server that doesn't inherit from QTcpServer and just uses an object of QTcpServer.

### Second question:

Is it wrong to run only one method in a other thread? Because I’ve learned it to do it like this in C# and in other Qt examples they put the current object in a other thread.

### Third question:

Why do I get this message:

> QObject: Cannot create children for a
> parent that is in a different thread.
> (Parent is MyServer(0x1ab1ca0),
> parent's thread is QThread(0x187a840),
> current thread is QThread(0x1acfa90)

When I start the run method.

Here is the source code:

myserver.h

```
#ifndef MYSERVER_H
#define MYSERVER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpServer>
#include <QtConcurrentRun>
#include <QFuture>
#include "myclienthandle.h"

class MyServer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyServer(QObject *parent = 0, const QString &ip = "Any", int port = 0);
    explicit MyServer(const MyServer &server);
    ~MyServer();
    QString IP() const;
    void setIP(const QString &ip);
    int Port() const;
    void setPort(int port);
    bool isAlive() const;


private:
    QTcpServer *m_qtcpserListener;
    QFuture<void> m_qftrRun;
    QString *m_qstrIP;
    int m_iPort;
    int m_iClientID;
    bool m_bRun;

    void run();

signals:
    void newConnection(MyClientHandle *clientHandle);

public slots:
    void start();
    void stop();
};

inline QString MyServer::IP() const
{
    return *m_qstrIP;
}

inline void MyServer::setIP(const QString &ip)
{
    m_qstrIP = new QString(ip);
}

inline int MyServer::Port() const
{
    return m_iPort;
}

inline void MyServer::setPort(int port)
{
    m_iPort = port;
}

inline bool MyServer::isAlive() const
{
    return m_bRun;
}

#endif // MYSERVER_H
```

myserver.cpp

```
#include "myserver.h"

MyServer::MyServer(QObject *parent, const QString &ip, int port) :
    QObject(parent), m_iClientID(0), m_bRun(false), m_qtcpserListener(0)
{
    setIP(ip);
    setPort(port);
}

MyServer::MyServer(const MyServer &server)
{
    MyServer(server.parent(), server.IP(), server.Port());
}

MyServer::~MyServer()
{
    if (m_qtcpserListener != 0)
        stop();
}

void MyServer::run()
{
    m_qtcpserListener = new QTcpServer(this);

    if (!m_qtcpserListener->listen(QHostAddress(IP()), Port()))
    {
        return;
    }

    while (m_bRun)
    {
        if (m_qtcpserListener->waitForNewConnection(5000))
        {
            QTcpSocket *qtcpsoNextPending = m_qtcpserListener->nextPendingConnection();
            emit newConnection(new MyClientHandle(qtcpsoNextPending));
        }
    }
}

void MyServer::start()
{
    m_bRun = true;
    m_qftrRun = QtConcurrent::run(this, &MyServer::run);
}

void MyServer::stop()
{
    m_bRun = false;
    if (m_qtcpserListener != 0 && m_qtcpserListener->isListening())
    {
        m_qtcpserListener->close();
    }
    m_qftrRun.cancel();
    m_qftrRun.waitForFinished();
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are running the `MyServer::run` function in a different thread (via `QtConcurrent::run`, but in the `MyServer::run` function you create a new TcpServer and give it a parent.  In Qt, the parent of an object created in one thread (the concurrent one) can't be an object owned by another thread (whatever thread the instance of `MyServer` is in, probably the first thread).

If you got past that, emitting signals in a different thread than the signaling object can also cause problems.  You may also run into problems in deletion, since you shouldn't delete a QObject in a different thread than the one that owns it.

My suggestion is to use [`QTcpServer`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qtcpserver.html)'s built-in threaded mechanism.  When you call `listen`, the function will return.  You could then connect to the [`newConnection()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qtcpserver.html#newConnection) signal to be notified when there is a connection pending, instead of waiting for a connection (which is what might lead you to think you needed to run the function concurrently).

Comment: Wich built-in threaded mechanism do you mean? Do you mean the moveToThread() methode?

Comment: @Paul Kreker: I didn't phrase things quite correctly when I said "built-in threaded mechanism".  What I meant was "built-in asynchronous abilities".  Put your retrieval and emitting of the next pending connection in a slot, hook that slot to the `m_qtcpserListener`'s newConnection signal, then just call listen on `m_qtcpserListener` when you want to start listening for connections.  That part doesn't need to be threaded at all.